# How to handle with multiple databases in prisma

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, graphql, prisma

I am using prisma and PostgreSQL. How to handle with graphql resolvers and typedefs when I am working with 2 databases and 2 schemas. I have graphql folder, where there are resolvers and typedefs for every table. Here is an example how does my working tree look:

> -grapgql
> ---table1
> ------resolvers.js
> ------typedefs.js
> ---table2
> ------resolvers.js
> ------typedefs.js
> ---resolvers.js
> ---typedefs.js
> -prisma1
> ---migrations
> ---schema1.prisma
> -prisma2
> ---migrations
> ---schema1.prisma
> -index.js

How does my server know which typedef and resolver file belongs to exactly this database? 
Thank you in advance)

Comment: Did you had a chance to look at this GitHub Issue: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2443#issuecomment-630679118 
There's a workaround specified through which you can use multiple databases and assign which schema is to be used for which PrismaClient instance.

Comment: A separate schema *per table* is highly unusual and means you can't support any graphql `type` which spans multiple tables without using federation. Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable `multiSchema` and create multiple schemas in datasource :

```
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["multiSchema"]
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
  schemas  = ["base", "transactional"]
}
```

Then apply this created schemas to your models:

```
model User {
  id     Int     @id
  orders Order[]

  @@schema("base")
}

model Order {
  id      Int  @id
  user    User @relation(fields: [id], references: [id])
  user_id Int

  @@schema("transactional")
}

enum Size {
  Small
  Medium
  Large

  @@schema("transactional")
}
```

Check [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/other/multi-schema) to more detailed information and how to deal with migration and pull